# asymptotic normality for MLE

Tags: convergence, fisher-information, slutsky-theorem

Suppose under suitable assumptions, $$[I(\theta_0)]^{1/2}(\hat{\theta} - \theta) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, I_p),$$
where $\hat{\theta}$ is maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$. $I(\theta_0) = I(\theta)|_{\theta=\theta_0}$ and $I(\theta)$ is the fisher information of sample distribution.

My class note says "$I(\theta_0)$ can be replaced by $I(\hat{\theta}_0)$, justified by Slutsky's theorem".

My question is why Slutsky's theorem justify it so that
$$[I(\hat{\theta})]^{1/2}(\hat{\theta} - \theta) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, I_p)$$
is correct?

Or do we have to assume that $\hat{\theta}$ converges to $\theta$ in probability?

Comment: Hint: if $[I(\hat\theta)]^{1/2} / [I(\theta)]^{1/2}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}1$, then...

Comment: @Sergio Thank you! We have $[I(\hat{\theta})]^{1/2}/[I(\theta)]^{1/2} \times [I(\theta)]^{1/2}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,I_p)$. But we assume that $\hat{\theta}\xrightarrow{p}\theta$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), if $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$ and $Y_n\overset{p}{\to}c$, where $c$ is a constant term, then $X_nY_n\overset{d}{\to}X c$. So if

- $[I_n(\theta)]^{1/2}(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, I_p)$ as $n\to\infty$,
- $[I_n(\hat\theta_n)]^{1/2}/[I_n(\theta)]^{1/2}\overset{p}{\to}1$ as $n\to\infty$,

where $\theta$ is the unknown parameter, $n$ is the sample size, and $\hat\theta_n$ is a sequence of ML estimators, then
$$\frac{[I_n(\hat\theta_n)]^{1/2}}{[I_n(\theta)]^{1/2}}[I_n(\theta)]^{1/2}(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)
=[I_n(\hat\theta_n)]^{1/2}(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)\overset{d}{\to} N(0,I_p)$$

This means that, when $n$ is large enough, the sampling distribution of MLEs is approximately normal.

Comment: Thank you. Why the following is wrong, then? $I(\theta_0)$ is constant, or we can say $X_n = I(\theta_0)^{1/2}\xrightarrow{d}I(\theta_0)^{1/2} = X$. $Y_n = \hat{\theta}-\theta \xrightarrow{p}0 = c$. Why not $X_nY_n = I(\theta_0)^{1/2}(\hat{\theta}-\theta) \xrightarrow{d} XY = 0$?

Comment: $I(\cdot)$ is a sequence, not a constant. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for letting me aware that this is a sequence.

Comment: Hi, I have an additional question and hope you could help me further. Why is it true that $I_n(\hat{\theta}_n)^{1/2}/I_n(\theta)^{1/2} \xrightarrow{p} 1$? Is it because of the consistency of $\hat{\theta}_n$

Comment: To get this you need that $\hat\theta_n$ goes to $\theta_0$ in probability (and continuity of $I_n^{1/2}$)

Answer (score 2):

You can show that if $[I(θ_0)]^{1/2}(\hat{θ}−θ_0)\overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0, I_p)$, then $\hat{\theta}\overset{P}{\longrightarrow} \theta_0$, so you don't need this assumption.

Comment: Can you please give more detail why this holds?

Comment: Well, you can prove it by hand by showing that $\mathbb{P}(\mid\hat\theta - \theta_0\mid > \varepsilon) \to 0$  for any $\varepsilon$.
Or you can use the result that : if $X$ converges to a constant $x$ in  distribution, then it also converges to $x$ in probability.
Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this.